# Interpreting Inf (Infinity) as answer to logloss function?

Tags: r, mathematical-statistics, interpretation, inference, log-loss

so I am using this logloss function

```
logLoss = function(pred, actual){
-1*mean(log(pred[model.matrix(~ actual + 0) - pred > 0]))
}
```

sometimes it is correctly giving me answers like 1.156051, 0.8714408 or 1.155732. However this time it gave Inf (Infinity) as answer. How do I correctly calculate or interpret it. My outcome variable is dichotomous, i.e. 1 or 0. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Logloss as you have given it should be equivalent to a binomial likelihood. So loss $\infty$ (corresponding to loglikeihood $-\infty$ means that the observations are incompatible with the model---something happened that the model says has probability zero.